# deploying a war to tomcat using python

Tags: python, tomcat, deployment, urllib2

I'm trying to deploy a war to a Apache Tomcat server (Build 6.0.24) using python (2.4.2) as part of a build process.

I'm using the following code

```
import urllib2
import base64

war_file_contents = open('war_file.war','rb').read()

username='some_user'
password='some_pwd'

base64string =  base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password))[:-1]
authheader =  "Basic %s" % base64string

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=war_file', data=war_file_contents)

request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
request.add_header("Authorization", authheader)

request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
url = opener.open(request)
```

the url.code is 200, and the url.msg is "OK". However the web archive doesn't appear on the manager list applications page.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you considered using jython and then using the Cargo library to manage your deployment to Tomcat (or any container, for that matter). It might save you some work:  http://cargo.codehaus.org/

Comment: Interestingly, it will have to run in jython at some point as part of a self extracting installer. So that could save a lot of effort. Good find, sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.

The urllib2.Request line needs to have a slash in front of the path so:-

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=/war_file', data=war_file_contents)
```

All then works fine.

Comment: Would love to, however get an "You can accept your own answer in 2 days message"